cypress - Element covered by another element after angular upgrade
I have a cypress test which has started to fail after the angular upgrade. Its complaining that the element to be clicked is covered by another element when actually it is not. I have attached the screenshot of the error on cypress runner and also of the dom. Any suggestion what is going wrong over here. thanks

Dom

I am using a function to select the dropdown option


selectOptionByOptionValue(formField, valueToFind) {

        formField.then(($el) => {
            if ($el.attr('aria-owns') !== undefined) {
                console.log('use aria-owns');
                formField
                    .invoke('attr', 'aria-owns')
                    .then(id => {
                        cy.get(`#${id}`)
                            .contains(valueToFind)
                            .click();
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("use aria-control?")
                formField
                    .click()
                    .invoke('attr', 'aria-controls')
                    .then(id => {
                        cy.get(`#${id}`)
                            .contains(valueToFind)
                            .click();
                    });
            }
        })




Which elements are you querying in the HTML? You've underlined a couple but it's not clear what the correlation is between HTML and test code.

So, I am trying to click element data-cy="reason" and passing it as 'formField' to the function abd valueToFind is the dropdown option, if that makes sense

So formField must be the result of a Cypress query - you might have some luck passing the selector string instead of the actual query result. Cypress says that you shouldn't pass around the result of a query because they get stale (the page updates and the query result is no longer valid).

Anyway, you should update the question with that information or it might get closed for being too vague.

Also you should post the HTML as text as it makes it easier to check out potential answers. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful
